# Can someone help me building this method?

Tags: c#

So, I am making a card game named Crazy 8. In which I am up to building a hand class.

The problem is that hand class has these two methods which I am unable to construct.
RemoveCard(Card): boolean  (Remove the given Card from the Hand, if possible. Return true if successful)
+RemoveCardAt(int): boolean (Remove the Card at the index given by the integer parameter. Return true if successful.)

btw the card is stored in a list suppose, it's named _hand.

I tried using for loops to get to the given card and then using _hand.remove(card) and then return true. but the test suit says that I am wrong.

```
public Boolean RemoveCard(Card card)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _hand.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (_hand[i] == card)
                {
                    _hand.RemoveAt(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
```

I want to know if my logic is correct?

Comment: "but the test suit says that I am wrong." How should we know what your test is doing and therefor why your code may or may not be whrong?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/njdfgl,

Comment: You can get rid of you method and just call _hand.Remove(card);

Comment: I used _hand.Remove(card) ... idk why it doesnot work..

Comment: The problem is likely with `==`, since this will only compare references, and not the values of the cards themselves.

Comment: (didn't mean to hit send), the solution is to either (a) Overload `==`, or (b) Use `.Equals` and override it for your Card class.

Comment: I tried using _hand[i].Equals(card) {_hand.Remove(card) return true;}

Comment: http://prntscr.com/njdmuf

Comment: Just using .Equals isn't enough, as KookieMonster said, you need to override the .Equals method for your Card class.See MS docs for an explanation and code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher http://prntscr.com/njdrhr I guess i did it already.

Comment: That should be `public override bool Equals` in order to override the method. Also, please, in future, don't post screenshots. Instead edit your question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KookieMonster did point out the direction of where to look for.
You need to implement comparison and equality operators for your class `Card`.
You can do this by either implementing the interfaces `IEquality` and `IComparable` (if i am right), or write your own static method that checks if two given card objects are the same.

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong. IEquality doesn't exist and IComparable doesn't deal with equality but with greater than, less than etc. operators.

Comment: I just tried it out in VS 2017, the interface i meant to cite was `IEquatable`, or `IEqualityComparer`...

Comment: Yes, I was just looking for the correct interface class for equality, but you beat me to it :) Still, worth pointing out that, while it's better practice to implement IEquatable, it's not strictly speaking necessary.

Comment: Thats right, sometimes it seems to be a bit of massive overhead to implement all the necessary interfaces.